# ¿How to ESCAPE Ñ on oracle sql?

Tags: oracle, escaping

¿How to ESCAPE  Ñ on oracle sql ?`alter table docentes 
add constraint ch check (upper(nombre like  'NARIÑO')`

HOW TO ESCAPE THE Ñ

THANKS

Comment: What do you mean by escaping?

Comment: Do you have an error? Or does this "unusual" character prevent you from achieving something?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ASCII('ñ') FROM DUAL; 
SELECT ASCII('Ñ') FROM DUAL;

SELECT CHR(241) FROM DUAL;
SELECT CHR(209) FROM DUAL;
```

So, You can put

```
add constraint ch check (upper(nombre like  'NARI'||CHR(209)||'O');
```

or

```
add constraint ch check (upper(nombre like  'nari'||CHR(241)||'o');
```